# IIS Request app pool by domain and different app pool for request by IP

Tags: c#, iis, application-pool

I have two application pools:
- App1 for request by IP
- App2 for request by domain

But I don't know the reason why in App1 I have request from domain. How to solve that?

Domain has different IP.

Thanks

Comment: Which port do they use? Did they each of the apps created as different applications on IIS?

Comment: Web apps and application pools are different things. Your description is ambiguous, so I think before you learn more about IIS and come back to add more info to this question (screen shots and so on), it cannot be answered.

Comment: Each apps use 80 port and are different applications on IIS.